# require:ngModel vs. scope: { ngModel: '=' } on AngularJS Directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi which is better? What is the difference? What are the pros and cons?

Here is the comparision code between the two:

**scope: { ngModel:'=' }**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="app">

<input ng-model="code"></my-directive>

</div>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  app = angular.module('app', []);

  app.directive('input', function(){
   return {
    scope: {
     ngModel: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){
     scope.$watch('ngModel', function(value){
      console.log(value);
     })
    }
   }
  });
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**require: 'ngModel',**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="app">

<input ng-model="code"></my-directive>

</div>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  app = angular.module('app', []);

  app.directive('input', function(){
   return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel){
      attrs.$observe('ngModel', function(value){
        scope.$watch(value, function(newValue){
          console.log(newValue);
        });
      });
    }
   }
  });
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

PS
Please be aware that both codes does the same. **Logs on the console with the value of the model**

Comment: Opinions are not the purview of SO.

Comment: "which is better" -> what are you trying to do? Difference: `require` gives you the enire `NgModelController` (thus you can e.g. plug into the conversion and validation pipelines of Angular), `scope =` gives you a binding to the same expression used by `ng-model` (and its underlying `NgModelController`).

Comment: What are the pros and cons?

Comment: @DeanChristianArmada added the pros and cons , its depends on your requirement which one to use

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With **scope:{ngModel:'='}** ,

It creates a directive with isolate scope , here basically  scopes are isolated and its doesn't inherit from the parent $scope , but values are passed into the directive which are required for this directive. if your use '=' then its two way data binding .

*well advantages and disadvantages depends on your requirement* .

**Advantages :**

- no need to use `$scope.$watch` every time , in order to update the view in your directive
  if values of the parent scope variables changes. '=' does the job .
- If directive is used with isolate scope , it will act as `reusable component` ,can use in multiple places in your application.
- scope variables passed to isolated scopes can be used in your `directive controller` directly even if the link function doesn't exist in your directive.

**disadvantages** :

- As scopes are isolated , will not get entire scope variables/functions of the parent controller .  needs to passed via the directive definition only
- cant able to use angular built-in methods for ng-model or ng-form to create api , [ngFormController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController) , [ngModelController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController)

---

with **require:'ngModel'**

**Advantages:**

- easy to  access entire parentsController scopes/functions when its used in nested directives
- good to create plugin as helps in modularity and as it has parent child relationship
- able to use angular built-in methods for ng-model or ng-form to create api out of them
- works well with events emitting and broadcasting (`publish-subscribe design pattern`).

**disadvantage**

- Should have `link function` in-order to get the parents controller and its scopes variables and methods.
- need to use `$scope.$watch` to update the view if parents scope variables changes.
- when controller As syntax is used . need to have $scope in-built methods like $scope.$watch and $scope.$on $scope.$emit , as it will be disturbance in directives controller or link with respect to use of both `this` and `$scope`